# HttpPost issues using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Facebook Connect in an iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

When implementing a Facebook Canvas app using an iframe the iframe does a post to my page.  This is fine, but it causes the validators to fire which brings up the page with errors on all of the input fields.

Is there anyway to not have the validators fire on this initial page load through the iframe canvas?

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
@model My.User

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)

     <input type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of using the framework and not making a hack, this is how I solved this... I am not set that this in the end all be all because there are some issues when implementing this with larger sets of permissions which are noted below.  The main issue is the constraint of the length of the URL.

First, when the user hits the site I am deciding to send them along based on my own set of rules, but still persist the signed request from Facebook via the URL.

```
if(Liked)
{
    return RedirectToAction("SimplyAnswerTheQuestion", new { sr = FBSignedRequest });
} else {
    return View(ElitistResponse(BetterThanYouObject));
}
```

Now the issue with this is that you will run out of space to store the signed request as a query string variable if you have been allowed more information about the FB user (i.e. Likes, Friends, etc.).  You could capture the signed request and store it before the redirect and then give the user a token in a cookie to pass along to access the data throughout the rest of the session.

Answer (score 0):

The validators are being fired because Facebook is doing an HTTP POST to the url being loaded into the iFrame.  By default, turn off your validators initially.  Only once when you get a signed_request POST parameter, from facebook then you turn them on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do you do that?  I wasn't aware there is a way to turn off the validators initially.

Comment: My assumption here is that you wrote the code that puts the validators into your form.  So your code doesn't have to put them into the code until they're really necessary to be used.

Comment: That code snippet does not include MVC3 validators, they're usually on a class extension file

Comment: Fixed the question to better represent.  Please see above.

Comment: Based on what you are saying... if I had 15 fields, I would have to remove the validator for all 15... that would mean they would not fire when the user fills out the form client-side.  I may be missing what you are trying to convey.

Comment: "Only once when you get a signed_request POST parameter, from facebook then you turn them on." from the original answer above.

Comment: I get what you are saying.  This still doesn't solve the problem. The original request is posted with a signed request to the form... if I turn off validation for the initial load, client side validation is gone.  It doesn't work.  This answer doesn't make sense unless you have an example based upon the provided code.

Comment: Nah, not playing those "Plz send me teh codez" games today.  I have nothing to prove.

Comment: Terrible that this is allowed as an answer.  Your solution isn't possible, but a negative vote by you is.  Awesome.

Comment: There are many ways to do validators, you're not hand-tied to use MVC3 style validator.  You are the master of your own domain and your own code, so take control of **your** code and make it your b*tch.  If you cannot figure out how to turn off/on the MVC3 validators, then write your own that you can turn on and off.  I've been doing my own validators for years, it's not Rocket Science.  The validators are getting fired off because of the HTTP Post facebook uses to send you the signed_request.

Comment: Coming from a guy who is playing the "Plz send me teh codez"...lol